# Docker compose with MongoDB (and Microsoft Azure)

Tags: mongodb, azure, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to launch an app on Microsoft Azure using docker-compose file. This is the error I'm getting in the logs

```
2019-06-18T18:12:55.319003252Z Successfully added user: {
2019-06-18T18:12:55.361353763Z     "user" : "myuser1",
2019-06-18T18:12:55.361371063Z     "roles" : [
2019-06-18T18:12:55.361387163Z         {
2019-06-18T18:12:55.361392063Z             "role" : "root",
2019-06-18T18:12:55.361396763Z             "db" : "admin"
2019-06-18T18:12:55.361401363Z         }
2019-06-18T18:12:55.361405563Z     ]
2019-06-18T18:12:55.361409964Z }
2019-06-18T18:12:55.367946981Z 2019-06-18T18:12:55.331+0000 E -        [main] Error saving history file: FileOpenFailed: Unable to open() file /home/mongodb/.dbshell: Unknown error
2019-06-18T18:12:55.399399764Z 
2019-06-18T18:12:55.399413964Z 2019-06-18T18:12:55.389+0000 I NETWORK  [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:50370 (0 connections now open)
2019-06-18T18:12:55.465992339Z /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
2019-06-18T18:12:55.466010339Z 
2019-06-18T18:12:58.011530247Z 2019-06-18T18:12:58.011+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
```

This is how my part for mongoDB looks like in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  ...other services
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: my-mongo
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - my-mongo:/data/db
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=myusername
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysupersecretpassword
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - myservices-net
```

The whole `docker-compose` file works locally on my machine, but it does not want to work on Microsoft Azure.

I've found [this](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/263#issuecomment-380764617) issue on GitHub but I'm not really sure how to apply the changes to my `docker-compose` file. Would really appreciate any help here!

Answer (score 1):

For your issue, the possible reason would be that the `networks` property is not supported in the compose file in Azure Web App. You can see all the Compose options supported and unsupported.

**Supported options**

- command
- entrypoint
- environment
- image
- ports
- restart
- services
- volumes

**Unsupported options**

- build (not allowed)
- depends_on (ignored)
- networks (ignored)
- secrets (ignored)
- ports other than 80 and 8080 (ignored)

For more details, see [Docker Compose options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container#docker-compose-options).